# Delete a number of records given by the number of records in a table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-delete, table-variable

I have a table variable called `@workorders`, this table are filled by a query:

```
DECLARE @workorders table
(id_workorder VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO @workorders SELECT DISTINCT(id_workorder) FROM CampaingControl WHERE id_campaing = @id;
--get each record of the table @workorders and delete of another table
```

Then, what I want is to go through each record of the table `@workorders` and delete a record with the value of the current record.

The table where I want to delete the records is called `WorkOrders`, this table have a column called `id_workorder`, for example:

Assuming the table variable `@workorders` have 3 records:

- OT-001-16
- OT-002-16
- OT-005-16

I need to implement a kind of while loop, to get each record on the table `@workorders` and for each record delete on the table `WorkOrders` where `id_workorder` = `@workorders (id_workorder VARCHAR(100))(Current record)`.

Comment: what do you mean by current record? how do you identify it in `workorders` table?

Comment: @vkp can you check again the question please?

Comment: Please note that temporary tables (`#WorkOrders`) are usually better than table variables (`@WorkOrders`) because table variables don't have statistics. More detail here https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/naga/2015/05/10/sql-server-performance-tuning-table-variable-vs-temporary-tables/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you not simply `INNER JOIN` the `@workorders` table in your `DELETE` statement?

```
DELETE w 
FROM workorders w INNER JOIN @workorders tw ON w.id_workorder = tw.id_workorder
```

Comment: Oh my God, I'm a little dumb. Thanks a lot.

Comment: No worries, sometimes just need another pair of eyes